# Subsetting polygons from shapefile using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, select-by-attribute, select

I have a shapefile of lakes with lots of polygons. The features I am interested in are only big lakes.

Is there any way to subset only the polygons I am interested in from the shapefile using ArcMap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Select (Analysis)](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm) tool which:

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
> typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
> and stores them in an output feature class.

For your SQL expression use something like "Shape_Area" >= 10000
(or whatever threshold value you want to use)